# Call to a member function format() on a non-object when dealing with date/time

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I'm trying to save some data to my database and need to format a date/time before the save.

my code is as follows:

```
public static function toSqlDate($date, $formatResult = true)
    {
        if (!$date)
        {
            return null;
        }

        $dateTime = DateTime::createFromFormat(DEFAULT_DATETIME_FORMAT, $date, new DateTimeZone(DEFAULT_TIMEZONE));

        return $formatResult ? $dateTime->format('Y-m-d') : $dateTime;
    }
```

When I try to save I get the following error in the debugger. the return line is the line highlighted as having the error.

> Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalErrorException
>   Call to a member function format() on a non-object

I'm not really sure how to even attempt to fix this. Is there a way I can output what each of the values being pulled in are before it throws the error? I'm trying to figure out what $dateTime is not being returned as an object.

any help would greatly be appreciated.

Some additional information:

I have created a utility/alias pointing the the function above and in my model repository I access it via the following.

```
public function save($publicId, $data)
{ 
...

    $form->date = Utils::toSqlDate($data['date']);
    ...
    $form->save();

...
}
```

and I have the following field in my view

```
{{ Former::text('date')->addClass('form-control form-control-inline input-medium default-date-picker')->data_bind("datePicker: date, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'") }}
```

Comment: How are you calling your `toSqlDate()`, can you show some code how it's being used?

Comment: @Unnawut I have added additinal information, thank you for your time.

Comment: Oh in that case just follow along @WereWolf - The Alpha 's answer and you should be set!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may create a `mutator` method in your `Eloquent Model` to make the conversion automatic when you save any model, for example, if you have a timestamp as `dob` in your `User` model then just add the following method in your `User` model:

```
public function setDobAttribute($value)
{
    $dt = \Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('Y/m/d', $value)->toDateString();
    $this->attributes['dob'] = $dt;
}
```

So you can just save a user model easilt, like:

```
$user = new User;
$user->dob = Input::get('dob');
// ...
$user->save();
```

The date will be automatically set for you using the `mutator/setDobAttribute` method defined in the `User` model, you don't need to do anything.